# GPUImage take a long time to save image in iphone4 4s . How can i do?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I define this function in a view class,     **filter = GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter**

```
[self.stillCamera capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter:self.filter withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage * image,NSError * error){
        @autoreleasepool {
            if (!image) {//得到照片发生错误
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(gpuImageCameraViewStillImageCaptured:image:error:)]) {
                    [self.delegate gpuImageCameraViewStillImageCaptured:self image:nil error:error];
                }
            }
            else{
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(gpuImageCameraViewStillImageCaptured:image:error:)]) {
                    [self.delegate gpuImageCameraViewStillImageCaptured:self image:image error:nil];
                }
            }
        }
    }];
```

I complete delegate in ViewController like this

```
NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(savePhotosThreadSingle:) object:image];
    [_threadQueue addOperation:op];
    [op release];
```

savePhotosThreadSingle: is a method to save image to photo library
**but it will take about 3s in iPhone4s to save this image** What should i do? thanks

Comment: How long does it take to save a similarly sized photo to the photo library without using GPUImage?

Comment: But i use thread to save the image,GPUImage ignore it.it will wait until the image is saved and lock the main thread. i found this funtion -(CGImageRef)newCGImageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)imageOrientation in GPUImageFilter.m may have some problem so that the GPUImage can't surppot multi thread to save image, could you tell me how to resolve it?Thanks

Comment: @duruochua.. How to solve this problem ... please help me.... it's urgent for me